# Remove attributes from XML using sed

Tags: linux, awk, sed

First of all, there might be other (better) options, but I'm bound to sed of awk in this case.
I have an XML file with the following contents.

```
<Field name="field1" type="String">AAAA</Field>
<Field name="field2" type="Integer">0</Field>
<Field name="field4" type="String">BBBB</Field>
```

Here I would like to change the contents using sed, to get the following result:

```
<field1>AAAA</field1>
<field2>0</field2>
<field4>BBBB</field4>
```

So remove the `"*Field name="*"`, the last quote from the name and the rest of the attributes up till the `*>*` and also I would like to change the last `</Field>` with the actual field name.
How to approach with `awk` or `sed`?

Removing from the first tag works with

```
sed 's/ type=".*"//' 
and
sed 's/Field name="//'
```

I'm not sure how to proceed with the replacing of the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's~[A-Z][^"]*"([^"]*)[^>]*([^/]*/)[^>]*~\1\2\1~' input_file
<field1>AAAA</field1>
<field2>0</field2>
<field4>BBBB</field4>
```

Comment: Works straight out of the box and also leaves other tags in tact. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `sed` code. Using `-E` option to enable ERE(extended regular expression). Using `sed`'s capability to create capturing groups(through regex) and values captured in those capturing groups are being used later in substitution.

```
sed -E 's/^<Field name="([^"]*)"[^>]*>([^<]*)<.*$/<\1>\2<\/\1>/' Input_file
```

Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BYBFES/1) for used regex for understanding purposes only.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With `awk` please try following `awk` code. Written and tested with shown samples. Making field separator as `<Field name=`, `"`, `>` and `<` for all the lines. In main block printing 3rd and 7th fields along with tags s per required output.

```
awk -F'^<Field name=|"|>|<' '{print "<"$3">"$7"</"$3">"}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** With GNU `awk` using its `match` function where using regex and its creating capturing groups out of it to store values into array named `arr` which are being printed later to achieve goal here.

```
awk '
match($0,/<Field name="([^"]*)"[^"]*"[^>]*>([^<]*)</,arr){
  print "<"arr[1]">" arr[2] "</"arr[1]">"
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Another sed:

```
sed -E 's/^[^"]+"([^"]+)("[^"]+){2}">([^<]+).*$/<\1>\3<\/\1>/' file.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

as simple as elegant

```
awk -F "[\"><]" '{print "<"$3">" $7 "<"$3">"}' input_file
```

explanation 
use '','<','>' as delimiter separate each line into several column fields 
then print what you need